# How to show the overlay 'No rows to show' in ag-grid , when the grid data is empty?

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

How to show the overlay 'No rows to show' in ag-grid , when the grid data is empty? I am getting the 'No rows to show overlay' , but the grid is still showing the data fetched earlier.

Answer (score 1):

How are you loading the data ?

If you use a custom datasource you have to call the callback with empty data.

Otherwise it should work with a api.setRowData([]); see http://ag-grid.com/angular-grid-api/index.php